# How can i find all network printer on my iis8 c# web-api application?

Tags: c#, iis-8, network-printers

My C#-Application hosted on IIS 8 can't find the installed network printers. When I run my application on my notebook they return all of my installed network printers.

I Tried

- Changing the `ApplicationPool` Identity to a user with print permission.
- Creating a local printer with a pointer to the network printer.

My Code

```cs
List<NetworkPrinter> availablePrinter = new List<NetworkPrinter>();
var printerQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * from Win32_Printer where Network = 'True'");

foreach (var printer in printerQuery.Get())
{
    var Name = printer.GetPropertyValue("ShareName").ToString();
    var IP = printer.GetPropertyValue("PortName").ToString();
    availablePrinter.Add(new NetworkPrinter()
    {
        IP = IP,
        Name = Name,
    }) ;

}
return availablePrinter;
```

Comment: I tried your code on my side in IIS and all installed network printers can be detected. So have you tried to run the same code out side IIS? Did you get the same result in the same server? If not, it is suggested to capture a first chance exception dump to check what's going on there.

Comment: Yes, outside iis i get all printers. The problem is i get no exception. The result from the query is empty :/

Comment: When i request my local printer from iis then i get only one with the Name: Microsoft XPS Document Writer

Comment: Have you tried to switch Application pool identity to localsytem? It looks like there was some isolation when querying win32_printer class in IIS. Besides, have you  tried to do a self-host for this web application?